# Couldn't target the organization using CF CLI

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am learning to use Bluemix and was trying to access my application using the Cloud Foundry command-line interface. But after logging in using my Bluemix ID at the CF CLI, I am not able to target the organization. On the Bluemix dashboard in my browser, the organization is visible. Is there a bug?

Comment: What command are you using? Are you seeing any error messages you can share with us?

Comment: command  am using is:

Comment: command  am using is: cf target -o Organisation_name

Comment: I think your org only exists in one region. Try changing the API endpoint you are using. Bluemix uses different endpoints for different regions. https://api.ng.bluemix.net = US South https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net = UK https://api.au-syd.bluemix.net = Sydney

Answer (score 1):

After running `cf login` some organisation should have been set as the target.

- Run `cf target` to get the current target information
- Run `cf orgs` to get the available organisations
- Run `cf spaces` to get the available spaces in the organisation
- Run `cf target -o organisation_name -s space_name` to target the correct organisation and space

Each organisation can have multiple spaces. Each space can have multiple applications. With the correct organisation and space set as targets the currently deployed applications can be listed with `cf apps`.

Organisations can span regions but may not. Check if the organisation is present in other regions by changing the API endpoint.

- US South https://api.ng.bluemix.net
- UK https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net
- Sydney https://api.au-syd.bluemix.net

Comment: I am doing the same.After using [cf orgs] Output comes [No orgs found].
Whereas,i have an organisation and a space as well.

Answer (score 0):

change the region API endpoint to the region that appears in your account

Comment: Please check out [How to Write a Good Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and include necessary details to address the question